# Does using a custom checkbox require the use of ARIA attributes?

Tags: html, wai-aria

I have a checkbox I modify with an image overlay. Does adding this overlay require the use of ARIA attributes for screen readers to understand? Or does the fact that I'm still using the native HTML checkbox make this unnecessary?

```
<div class="checkbox-overlay">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="true">
    <input type="hidden" value="false">
    <span class="overlay"></span>
    <span>Checkbox Label</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

[Here is the working example.](https://jsfiddle.net/tdhv67sx/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your overlay is using a background image so that will be hidden from the screen reader so that's ok.

However, your jsfiddle example has a `tabindex="0"` on the `<label>` which will be confusing.  That will allow the keyboard user and the screen reader user to <kbd>tab</kbd> to the label but you can't select the label.

The next <kbd>tab</kbd> will move to the actual checkbox (which is "behind" your overlay) and that's where they can press <kbd>space</kbd> to select the checkbox.  But the problem there is that since the real checkbox is behind the overlay, the user won't see a visible focus indicator.  It'll be covered up by the overlay.  Perhaps that's what you were trying to fix with `<label tabindex="0">`.  I think you can fix this problem using the `:focus-within` style.